# Error kivy: AttributeError: 'Final' object has no attribute 'ganar_juego'

Tags: python-3.x, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm creating my popup in kivy, but when I call the `self.win_game` attribute in `def on_kv_post` I get this error. I do not know why.

```
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivymd.app import MDApp


class Final(Popup):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.ganar_juego = kwargs["ganador"]
        print(self.ganar_juego)
        
    def on_kv_post(self, base_widget):
        #Selecciono si ha ganado o no
        self.ids.ganar.text = str(self.ganar_juego)
```

**This is the error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
   File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Aplicaciones\AppNumdle\libs\clases.py", line 168, in calcular_expersion
     popup = Final(ganador = True)
   File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Aplicaciones\AppNumdle\libs\final.py", line 9, in __init__
     super().__init__()
   File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Aplicaciones\AppNumdle\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\modalview.py", line 195, in __init__
     super(ModalView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Aplicaciones\AppNumdle\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\anchorlayout.py", line 68, in __init__
     super(AnchorLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Aplicaciones\AppNumdle\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\layout.py", line 76, in __init__
     super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Aplicaciones\AppNumdle\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 372, in __init__
     self.dispatch('on_kv_post', self)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Aplicaciones\AppNumdle\libs\final.py", line 15, in on_kv_post
     self.ids.ganar.text = str(self.ganar_juego)
 AttributeError: 'Final' object has no attribute 'ganar_juego'
```

I would like to be able to solve the problem